# Personalise html via attribute and not via subscriber key

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

What we are trying to do is send two triggered emails to the subscriber Subscriber_Key=`123` in each emails we want to mention the friend that that subscriber has referred to us.

To do so we need to make sure that we can retrieve during the send a friend unique identifier to lookup in the data extension and personalize our HTML each time with the friend Name.

How can we achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the values from your triggered send data extension and iterate through them like this:

```
%%[
var @rows, @row, @rowCount, @numRowsToReturn, @i

set @numRowsToReturn = 0 /* 0 means all, max 2000 */
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("TRIGGERED_SEND_DE",@numRowsToReturn,"friend_name desc","subscriber_key", _subscriberkey)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowCount > 0 then

    for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

      var @friendSubscriberKey, @promoCode, @friendName
      set @row = row(@rows,@i) /* get row based on counter */
      set @friendSubscriberKey = field(@row,"friend_subscriber_key")
      set @promoCode = field(@row,"friend_unique_identifier_promo_code")
      set @friendName = field(@row,"friend_name")

    ]%%

      Row %%=v(@i)=%%
      <br>friend_subscriber_key: %%=v(@friendSubscriberKey)=%%
      <br>friend_unique_identifier_promo_code: %%=v(@promoCode)=%%
      <br>friend_name: %%=v(@friendName)=%%

    %%[

  next @i ]%%

%%[ else ]%%

No friends

%%[ endif ]%%
```